# curl_exec(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory

Tags: php, laravel

When I fetched 2k data from BigQuery using Google's client library vai my API, everything works perfectly fine. But as soon as I increase the data limit to 3k or more it throws the following error:

```
curl_exec(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory.
```

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIndD.png)

I'm using postman to test my APIs. And the system is running on top of XAMPP.

I googled the error message but did not find the exact issue I was facing. Again, I tried giving permissions to both /tmp folder in my local machine and /xampfiles/temp folder inside /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles but nothing worked and I'm still getting the same error. I increased many limit parameters like output_buffering, memory_limit, execution_time etc in php.ini file as I was not sure what to do.

The issue seems too trivial but it's giving me headache. I would be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: The error you're facing is produced by php_stream_temp_write() - it's unrelated to BigQuery.  Please consider removing the BigQuery tag.

Comment: @MichaelMoursalimov Just removed the BigQuery tag. Can you please help me how to solve the error produced by php_stream_temp_write() ?

Answer (score 1):

If upload_tmp_dir is not defined in /etc/php.ini, then Apache uses /tmp

Ensure that whichever temp directory you are using is Apache writeable and has the t sticky bit.

Then restart Apache.